# Using np.diagflat only along second dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array (`x_train`) with shape of `(5094, 512)` and I want to turn the 1d slice of the second dimension into a 2d diagonal array. I am trying below code:

```
x_train_diag = np.zeros((5094, 512, 512))
x_train_diag = np.apply_along_axis(np.diagflat, x_train, 1)
```

As an example, if I have 5094 batches of [1, 1, ..., 1] data arrays; instead I want to have 5094 batches of

```
[1 0 0
 0 1 0
 ...
 0 0 1]
```

I am getting this vague TypeError:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Where do you define `x_train`?

Comment: Do you want to `np.broadcast_to`?

Comment: I was more trying to create a diagonal array with 0s everywhere else and data only along diagonal, broadcast would multiply the data all over second dimension, or if I understood it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's advanced indexing together with broadcasting. Here is a smaller example:

```
import numpy as np

# Your inputs here
x_train = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(4, 3)

# Solution:
H, W = x_train.shape
x_train_diag = np.zeros((H, W, W), dtype=x_train.dtype)
rows, cols = np.indices((H, W), sparse=True)

x_train_diag[rows, cols, cols] = x_train
```

results:

```
>>> x_train
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
>>> x_train_diag
array([[[ 1,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  2,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  3]],

       [[ 4,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  5,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  6]],

       [[ 7,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  8,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  9]],

       [[10,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 11,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 12]]])
```

Comment: thank you, much simpler than from what I was trying!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you ?
I used stack upon the list of your diagonal matrices.

```
# generating the data as a 2D matrix
nb_batches = 5
nb_data = 7
a = np.random.randint(0, 9, (nb_batches, nb_data))
print(a)
# turning it into a 3D matrix (list of diag matrices)
new_a = np.stack([np.diag(a[i,:]) for i in range(nb_batches)])
print()
print(new_a.shape)
print(new_a[0])
```

Result :

```
[[1 7 2 5 1 2 8]
 [5 8 6 2 4 6 6]
 [5 2 8 5 2 8 5]
 [3 3 0 6 5 3 3]
 [1 0 8 8 4 0 5]]

(5, 7, 7)
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 7 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 5 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 8]]
```

Comment: thanks, it works exactly as I was trying to do

Comment: For some really big matrices, using numpy.stack can take a lot of time so a less elegant but better version might be to first create your final matrice as a big 3D matrix full of zeros and with the right dtype (integers, float...) and then fill it (this way u can already check if you have the necessary memory).